# ERROR: Error installing sass: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby, sass, rubygems, package

I was trying to install sass. I did manage to install it via npm (1.14.1 compiled with dart2js 2.0.0), however I need to install it with Ruby (Ruby Sass 3.5.6.). Now, here is the error when I run "sudo gem install sass"

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing sass:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20181004-3909-1iytz3s.rb extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
--with-ffi_c-dir
--without-ffi_c-dir
--with-ffi_c-include
--without-ffi_c-include=${ffi_c-dir}/include
--with-ffi_c-lib
--without-ffi_c-lib=${ffi_c-dir}/lib
--with-libffi-config
--without-libffi-config
--with-pkg-config
--without-pkg-config 

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/
2.3.0/mkmf.rb:456:in 'try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
from 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/
2.3.0/mkmf.rb:571:in `block in try_compile'
from 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/
2.3.0/mkmf.rb:524:in `with_werror'
from 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/
2.3.0/mkmf.rb:571:in `try_compile'
from 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/
2.3.0/mkmf.rb:1091:in `block in have_header'
from 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/
2.3.0/mkmf.rb:942:in `block in checking_for'
from 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/
2.3.0/mkmf.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
from 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/
2.3.0/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
from 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/
2.3.0/mkmf.rb:350:in `block in postpone'
from 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/
2.3.0/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
from 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/
2.3.0/mkmf.rb:346:in `postpone'
from 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/
2.3.0/mkmf.rb:941:in `checking_for'
from 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/
2.3.0/mkmf.rb:1090:in `have_header'
from extconf.rb:16:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-18/2.3.0/ffi-1.9.25/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/ffi-1.9.25 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-18/2.3.0/ffi-1.9.25/gem_make.out
```

I have tried to update Ruby, delete sass installed via npm, update xcode dev-tools as some suggested. But nothing works. I have no idea what is the reason since I had sass before updating to new Mac OS Mojave from 0.

Here is the mkmf.log file:

```
package configuration for libffi is not found
"xcrun clang -o conftest - 
I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework
/Versions/2.3/usr/include/ruby-2.3.0/universal-darwin18 - 
I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/
include/ruby-2.3.0/ruby/backward - 
I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/
ruby-2.3.0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE - 
D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT    -g -Os -pipe - 
DHAVE_GCC_ATOMIC_BUILTINS conftest.c  -L. - 
L/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib -L.     
-lruby.2.3.0  -lpthread -ldl -lobjc "
In file included from conftest.c:1:
In file included from 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/
ruby-2.3.0/ruby.h:33:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/include/
ruby-2.3.0/ruby/ruby.h:24:10: fatal error: 'ruby/config.h' file not found
#include "ruby/config.h"
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so the solution was found. If you have this error. Do this:

1. Install rvm (https://rvm.io/)
2. Then I had to run this command to make rvm work:

if sudo grep -q secure_path /etc/sudoers; then sudo sh -c "echo export rvmsudo_secure_path=1 >> /etc/profile.d/rvm_secure_path.sh" && echo Environment variable installed; fi

3. next with rvm I deleted ruby:

rvm remove ruby

4. and lastly install ruby:

rvm install ruby

5. not sure if this step was required, but this is what I had in my console: Ruby was built without documentation, to build it run: rvm docs generate-ri

   So I also ran this command. And after that I was finally able to sudo gem install sass.

Now it works!

Comment: Basically just delete your ruby and install it again. It solved the issue for me.

Comment: I installed rvm, then simply ran `rvm install ruby`. I did not need to do anything else as the installation seemed to install over my mac's native installation of ruby.

Answer (score 1):

Perform following steps in mac to install SASS error free

1. Install gpg
   brew install -v gpg
2. Install gpg keys
   gpg2 --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
3. Allow curl to run without checking SSL (else command #4 will throw an error)
   echo insecure >> ~/.curlrc
4. Install rvm
   \curl -sSL -k  https://get.rvm.io | bash
5. To use rvm, you will get an output after running command in #3 like:
   To start using RVM you need to run `source /Users/ymehta/.rvm/scripts/rvm`
   Copy paste command and hit Enter
6. Remove existing ruby version
   rvm remove ruby
7. Install ruby
   rvm install ruby
8. rvm docs generate-ri
9. Install sass
   sudo gems install sass
10. Check sass version
    sass --version

Same steps can be found at https://gist.github.com/Yashvi-Mehta/9ad81330d1703f12a00b63cf20c9cdb3